# How to configure api http request with load testing

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load

I want to test hotel booking application api in jmeter.
I want to test this application with first 2 search api with increasing load and then decreasing the load with normal booking api for bookin process.
How can I configure load test for each http request under testplan?

I have created normal testplan add all the api under the testplan and added the test plan configuration

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about how to configure JMeter virtual users for simulating increasing and decreasing load you can go for [Open Model Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Open_Model_Thread_Group):

For example this setup:

```
rate(0/sec) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(10/sec)random_arrivals(1 min) rate(10/sec)rate(10/sec) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(0/sec)
```

will result into the following workload model:

[image]

See [Rethinking Load Configuration With JMeter’s Open Model Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-model-thread-group) article for more information and examples of setting various workload models like spikes